# jQuery add class active to third dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamically-generated

I have this div:

```
<div class="mm_vert_container" style="display: block;"></div>
```

After runing jQuery code I dynamically add `div` inside above `mm_vert_container` and my code looks like this:

```
<div class="mm_vert_container" style="display: block;">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
    <div>D</div>
    <div>E</div>
    <div>F</div>
</div>
```

So I need to add to every third `div` if exists class active so needs to look like this:

```
<div class="mm_vert_container" style="display: block;">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div class="active">C</div>
    <div>D</div>
    <div>E</div>
    <div>F</div>
</div>
```

I try using jQuery code to add class active to third div:

```
$(".mm_vert_container div:nth-child(2)").addClass("active");
```

But it does not add class active to third element. I think that problem is dynamically generated divs and then DOM element using above jQuery code don't see dynamically generated divs and this is why is not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly note that indexes when using `nth-child` selectors start at `1`, so the 'C' element is at index `3`, not `2`.

To add the class to every third element, use `nth-child(3n)`, like this:

```js
$(".mm_vert_container div:nth-child(3n)").addClass("active");
```

```css
.active { 
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #C00; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mm_vert_container" style="display: block;">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
    <div>D</div>
    <div>E</div>
    <div>F</div>
</div>
```

Also note that jQuery isn't required here as the `nth-child()` selector is well supported in CSS directly:

```css
.mm_vert_container div:nth-child(3n) { 
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #C00; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mm_vert_container" style="display: block;">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
    <div>D</div>
    <div>E</div>
    <div>F</div>
</div>
```

The latter would be the far better solution because it de-couples the JS logic from the UI, and also means that any child `div` elements you add dynamically at a later time in the page lifecycle will automatically be given the styling; ie. you won't need to update the DOM again manually.

Comment: Thanks using css works but using jQuery code does not...does it have problems that div is dynamically added?

Comment: Yes it would - you need to execute that line of jQuery code *after* the elements have been added - presumably in the callback of your AJAX request. This is the issue I alluded too when I mentioned that the CSS approach is far better.

Comment: All answers are very usefull and i added to last because i try all  solutions and works very nice...i vote to all answers and accepted yours as accepted as your post are very detail and first posted...thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 2):

find child element of `.mm_vert_container` with [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method and [`:nth-child() Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) to selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent..

```
$(".mm_vert_container div:nth-child(3n)").addClass("active");
```

Comment: Note that this gets the third element only, not *every* third element.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$(".mm_vert_container div:nth-child(2)").addClass("active");` the code should be `$(".mm_vert_container div:nth-child(3)").addClass("active");` to effect the third child, because `nth-child(2)` means the second child.

Its better to use `$(".mm_vert_container div:nth-child(3n)").addClass("active");` if you want to effect every third child, then you wont be needing a loop. You can do this only by CSS.

I hope this helps.

Thanks.